# Simple Calculator C++

Tags: c++

I wrote this program for a homework assignment. I am not getting the correct output. I was told it is because I am not resetting PreviousResult between sets of calculations, yet I have no idea how to do that.
The output should be:

Please enter a filename: calc.txt

The result of calculation 1 is: 26

The result of calculation 2 is: 2

The result of calculation 3 is: 0

Instead I am getting 4 calculations, with calculation 3 = 1, and 4 = 0

The calc.txt file is:

3
add 5 4
add_prev 4
mul_prev 2

1
sub 3 1

1
div_prev 2

My code:

```
// Header Files
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// Declaring variables
int PreviousResult = 0;
string command;
string filename = "calc.txt";
int x,y,z;
int result = 0;
int numCommands = 0;
int operation = 1;

//Prompts the user to enter the text file name.
cout << "Please enter a filename: ";

cin >> filename;

//Declaring an ifstream object and opening the file
ifstream myfile(filename.c_str());
myfile.open("calc.txt");

//Will check to see if file exists. If not, it will output the following.
if(!myfile)
{
    cout << "The file doesn't exist." <<endl;

    return 0;
}

//While loop- read the file until the end is reached.
while(!myfile.eof())
{
    myfile >> numCommands;
    for(int i = 0; i < numCommands; i++)
    {
        myfile >> command;
        //Addition
        if (command=="add")
        {
            myfile >> x >> y;
            PreviousResult = x + y;
        }
        //Subtraction
        else if (command == "sub")
        {
            myfile >> x >> y;
            PreviousResult = x - y;
        }
        //Multiplication
        else if (command == "mul")
        {
            myfile >> x >> y;
            PreviousResult=x*y;
        } 
        //Division
        else if(command=="div")
        {
            myfile >> x >> y;
            PreviousResult = x / y;
        }
        else if (command == "add_prev")
        {
            myfile >> z;
            PreviousResult += z;
        }
        else if (command == "sub_prev")
        {
            myfile >> z;
            PreviousResult -= z;
        }
        else if (command == "mul_prev")
        {
            myfile >> z;
            PreviousResult *= z;
        }
        else if (command == "div_prev")
        {
            myfile >> z;
            PreviousResult /= z;
        }
    }

    result = PreviousResult;

    //Print the results.
    cout << "The result of calculation " << operation <<" is: " << result <<  endl;
    //The count is incremented by 1
    operation ++;
}
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the calc.txt file?

Comment: Here is the calc.txt file:
3
add 5 4
add_prev 4
mul_prev 2

1
sub 3 1

1
div_prev 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't resetting PreviousResult after you perform the calculations. So in calculation 2, you are setting PreviousResult to 2, setting result = PreviousResult, and then displaying the result.  The problem is that once you go into calculation 3, PreviousResult still equals 2.  That means calculation 3 is computing 2 divided by 2 instead of 0 divided by 2, giving you the incorrect answer.

So after you set Result = PreviousResult, you need the line

```
PreviousResult = 0;
```

As for the 4th calculation, while(!myfile.eof()) can cause inconsistent results. There may be a newline character causing it to try and read the next empty line.  Add myfile.ignore() right after the opening brace of the while loop and that should fix the issue.

Comment: All that helped! It did fix the third calculation, but I am still getting 4 calculations for some reason which is causing it to be wrong.

Comment: Instead of using while(!myfile.eof)) use while(myfile >> numCommands).

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting your program correctly, you are right that one of your problems is from the PreviousResult not being reset.  You declared and initialized PreviousResult at the beginning with this line

```
int PreviousResult = 0;
```

Resetting it is as simple as resassigning its value such as

```
PreviousResult = 0;
```

As for why you are getting 4 calculations instead of 3,

```
while(!myfile.eof())
```

will loop 1 more time than you intend it to because eof() only returns false after the input stream has read the end of file.  That does not occur until
`myfile >> numCommands;`.  An Alternative is to do

```
while(myfile >> numCommands)
```

and the while loop will terminate when there are no more things to be read.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.